# Matrix of an induced map $\beta_2: V \to V^*$ by a bilinear form on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a bilinear form $\beta$ on $V=\mathbb{R^3}$ given by

$$\beta(x, y) = x^T Ay$$

with $$A = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  17 &  -2 & -2 \\
  -2 & 6 & 4 \\
  -2  & 4  & 6 \\ 
 \end{bmatrix}$$

I need to find the matrix $M^{B}_{B^{*}}(\beta_2)$ which represents the induced map $$\beta_2: V \to V*$$ $$v \mapsto \beta(v, -)$$

Let $B$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $B^*$ the corresponding basis of $V^*$

---

My attempt: I know that the corresponding basis of $V^*$ are the projections on the $i$-th coordinate $$p_i: V \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$v \mapsto v_i$$

I also know that to find the matrix I need to find the image of every basis vector in $B$ and represent it as a linear combination of basis vectors $p_j$

So for the image of $e_i$ I get the $i$-th column of $A$, then the $j$-th entry is the coefficient of $e^*_j$.

To find the representative matrix I need to form the $i$-th column by taking the coefficients of $e^*_j$

...which leaves me with the representative matrix which is exactly $A$.

Did I do something wrong? Where is my mistake?